# Why i cant punch a hole through the mesh?

Tags: modifiers, add-on

With the BoolTool Addon why i cant punch a hole. Why its making a groove. I check the orientation of both the faces. Scale and rotation are also 1 and 0. Any suggestion whats going wrong. Thanks

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is essentially a shading issue: use autosmooth in the property panel. That will avoid the rendering to be annoyed by the normals of the faces created by the boolean.

[image]

To fix the little tube that goes bad, just shift it a bit.

Also the tubes are opened at the bottom. They should be closed.

Comment: Thanks for the quick solution

Comment: Adding some loop cuts to the main part of the tube will help a lot, too. The boolean holes need to connect somewhere and there isn't a lot of geometry along the length.